# C++ pass array to function without copy

Tags: c++, arrays, c, pointers

I'm new to C/C++ and I want to know what is the proper way to pass array to function without copy for example:

```
void someFunction(uint8_t &array) {
    // some work here
}

int main() {
    uint8_t *array = (uint8_t*) malloc(sizeOf(uint8_t) * 100);
    someFunction(*array);
}
```

Is this way correct and does the array copy when I pass it to someFunction()?

Comment: 1) There is no such language as C/C++. What you are using is, clearly C++ (as you can't compile such code with C compiler) 2) What made you think, that passing `uint8_t*` to the function would copy the array?

Comment: Do you know of the way to pass array by copy?

Comment: A function defined as `void someFunction(uint8_t &array)` gets passed a **single** `uint8_t` by reference.

Comment: dont use `malloc` in C++, it isnt wrong here, but only by coincidence, and there is no reason to use it

Comment: In C, there's no way to pass an array to a function *except* by reference. In C++, you use vectors.

Comment: There is no array in your example.  You are using pointers.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I just wanted to know is it a correct way because I'm new to C++, so if I pass any type of value e.g. uint8_t, int, char, struct or an instance of some class by reference to some function it's prevent the argument from copying?

Comment: @easy_breezy Are you asking a C++ question or a C question? There are different ways for passing arrays to functions in C and in C++.

Comment: @easy_breezy "_I just wanted to know is it a correct way because I'm new to C++_ "In C++, if you want statically-sized array, you would use `std::array`, and if you wanted to use dynamically-sized array, you would use `std::vector`, and pass references to those.

Comment: @easy_breezy `int x[10];`  That is an array.  If you want to know how to pass that, then C++ has additional answers than `C` does.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius ok thank you, I've already try to use std::vector but them slow down my app and when I changed them to pointers everything works fine, and if I understand it correctly the way of working with arrays that I described above it's a C and not C++ ?

Comment: @easy_breezy "_I've already try to use std::vector but them slow down my app_" Then there's something wrong in how you use it (as in: your `std::vector` usage, and your pointer usage, aren't equivalent). Can't give advice on what's wrong in your usage, without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

You mix up some terminology. You aren't passing arrays you are passing reference to your allocated data. Arrays need to be fixed in size so you won't be able to dynamically allocate them (***Edit:** with that I mean you cant allocate them on the stack without knowing the size by compile time*). An easier way here would be to change the signature of the function to accept a pointer

```
void someFunction(uint8_t *array) { /* ... */ }
```

and then pass the pointer by value

```
someFunction(array);
```

I also advise you to use the `new` and `delete[]` operators designed for allocating such data in C++, but it's not necessary for this question.

**Edit:**
Of course, a safer way is to use the `std::vector` class for dynamic-length data and `std::array` class for static-length data.

Comment: "Arrays need to be fixed in size so you won't be able to dynamically allocate them" unclear what you mean. Arrays can be dynamically allocated. Also the advise to use `new` should at least come with a hint to `std::vector` or `std::array`. In modern C++ raw `new` should be avoided

Comment: @idclev463035818 Because he is new to C++ i didn't want to put too much information in this answer but I can adjust it based on your critique.